# How to convert the size of the HTML document from 68 Kb to the average of 33 Kb?

Tags: java, html, optimization, seo

I've been trying to overcome the issue of my website's HTML document size being too large at 68 Kb, well above the average of 33 Kb. I've attempted various strategies such as code optimization and resource management to bring it down to the recommended size, but unfortunately, I haven't seen any improvement in site speed. Any suggestions on what else I could try for optimal website performance.

I attempted various methods to reduce my HTML document size from 68 Kb to the recommended average of 33 Kb. This includes code optimization, minification, image compression, CSS and JavaScript optimization, and implementing caching and compression techniques. Despite these efforts, I haven't seen significant improvements in reducing the size.

Comment: Please show the `HTML`.

Comment: As a side note, image compression will not affect the size of the HTML document, except if images are inserted as `data:…` (instead of a path or a URL).

Comment: You may have to remove content.  It isn't possible to give you specifics without seeing the code for your specific case.